# How to get value instead of Promise from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a "value of Data" from Firebase Realtime Database. You can find my code below:

```
  async function getName() {
    const result = await firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.user.uid)
    .once('value').
    then(async function(snapshot) {
      console.log("SNapshot =>");
      console.log(snapshot.val().displayName); // returns "John Doe"

      const result2 = await snapshot.val().displayName;

      return result2;
    });

    return result; // returns "Promise Object"
  };
```

It returns "Promise". But i want to get value not promise.

How should i fix my code?

Thanks.

Comment: `async` functions return a Promise by contract - it is the way they work.

Comment: You can't get a value from the future. Return the promise, have the user wait for the value.

Comment: I only want to get a value of any data from my Firebase Realtime Database. It doesn't matter to use "async" function for me. How can i get value as `firebase.auth().currentUser.email`?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up use of async/await with then()/catch().  You should pick one syntax or the other, not both together in this case.  You are also trying to use await on something that is not a promise.  Just write your function like this:

```
async function getName() {
  const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.user.uid).once('value')
  return snapshot.val().displayName
}
```

And call it like this:

```
const name = await getName()
```

Comment: It still returns "Promise". How can i get any value of data from Firebase with a function ?

Comment: Async functions all return promises, no exceptions.  That's why I'm showing how to call getName using await to unwrap the promise.

Comment: How can i get value from Database as `firebase.auth().currentUser.email`? It returns `abc@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

The `getname` function is doing async operation so you can do:

```
try {
  await result = getName();
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

within an async function, or, if you prefer without async :

```
result.then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: While this *might* work, the entire getName function is poorly written and has way too many lines of code for what's necessary.

Comment: Thanks but it still returns "Promise".